# How do we address a function whose values are again functions?

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, terminology

One may call a function whose values are functions simply a function-valued function. But is there a canonical name for such an object?

A $k$-form on some open $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an example of such an object, for it assigns to every $x \in A$ exactly one alternating $k$-tensor on the tangent space $T_{x}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, which is a function $\prod_{1}^{k}T_{x}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you describe a situation in which you would *want* a name to describe all of these objects at once? Before giving something a name, one usually has a reason to give it a name.

Comment: Thank you. No urgency in fact. Out of pure curiosity and partly for unifying terminology for my own purpose. @MikeMiller

Comment: Perhaps inverse functional?